# How could I get a batch file to execute a vbs?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Can anyone help me execute a vbs from a batch file?
I am trying to execute this

```
''''Script to create manual system restore point without user intervention''''

If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " Run", , "runas", 1

Else

GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:Systemrestore").CreateRestorePoint "ManualRestorePoint", 0, 100

End If
```

Comment: just pass the vbs file name to cscript.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save the above script as `myscript.vbs`, you can call it from a batch file as `wscript myscript.vbs`.

You might want to run `wscript /?` to see if you want to pass any flags to suppress the banner, etc.