# Airflow to execute a file on Windows server

Tags: windows, bash, airflow, operator-keyword, directed-acyclic-graphs

We can use ‘Bash Operator’ to execute Unix commands. May I know the operator if we want to execute a file in Windows ?

Suppose if I want to execute below file on Windows server:
"E:\ETL_Processing\Automation\vbs\abcdefg.vbs".

Comment: cscript //NOLOGO "E:\ETL_Processing\Automation\vbs\abcdefg.vbs" ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. Can u pls explain ?

Comment: I do not know what Airflow is and how scripting works there. cscript is interpreter for visual basic code files. my comment above is an example of how to execute your file on Windows - ie. answer to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I get a batch file to execute a vbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879514/how-could-i-get-a-batch-file-to-execute-a-vbs)